# Grabar entidades relacionadas EF6 c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

tengo una estructura en la BD (sql server) en la cual tengo una entidad principal (paciente) y otras relacionadas (medicinas, parametrosClinicos, actividades, etc) es una relación uno a muchos, entendiendo que, pudiese llegar a ser que por ejemplo, tenga cero o mas detalles por cada maestro.
En la base de datos, por supuesto le indique a la relación entre las tablas de detalle y la tabla paciente, que utilizara regla de actualización: Cascada, tanto para el insert/update, como para el delete.

Al momento de grabar el paciente y las entidades relacionadas, las cuales algunas tienen datos y otras no, se me genera el siguiente error: "No se puede usar OriginalValues para entidades en el estado Added."

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?
Estoy usando EntityFramework 6.

Saludos

Comment: Cuando pasan estas cosas, frecuentemente es porque hay columnas en tu base de datos marcadas como NOT NULL, y sin embargo están recibiendo un valor null. Esto puede ser porque no le estas dando un valor a esa columna, o bien, estas metiendo una cadena mayor a la longitud del campo. Lo mejor es revisar tus campos y hacer una actualizacion al modelo.

Comment: si, eso es verdad, de hecho, huce otro ejemplo mas sencillo para probar ese tipo de errores, por ejemplo, asigne a un campo varchar(10) yna cadena mas latrga, y efectivamente falla por eso. tambien deje algunos campos en null a proposito, y el mensaje de error en esos casos es claro. el tema, es que aca me aparece ese mensaje que dice **No se puede usar OriginalValues para entidades en el estado Added.** y que no se a que se refiere.

Comment: Me disculpo si no fuí claro. Pero ese mensaje se obtiene cuando hay problemas de asignación en los campos como los que te mencioné. Otra cosa a tomar en cuenta es que la cadena vacía tambien se vuelve NULL, a menos que tengas activado el  parametro `AllowEmptyStrings`.
Como sugerencia aparte, en StackOverflow es mas fácil obtener ayuda si posteas tu código. Puede que sea algo muy sencillo de identificar si son muchos los ojos que lo ven.
Suerte!

Comment: Hola. habia olvidado comentar este tema. pues si, tenias razon en lo que decias. efectivamente habia una incongruencia en los valores que se asignaban a los campos en la grabacion de la tabla. muchas gracias por la ayuda. saludos